# I need to host my react app on my domain and my api on my subdomain with Nginx on the Ubuntu server and Nginx on Docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, devops, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

So basically, I have two Nginx processes. One runs on an ubuntu server itself (20.04 LTS) (for the frontend), and the other runs on docker on the ubuntu server (for the backend).

I have created a server block for both the front end and the backend but if I browse the backend on the subdomain (api.domain.com) it displays a 404 not found page with the current configuration.

The one running on the ubuntu server serves the react app with the server block below:

```
server {
        listen 80;
#       listen [::]:80;
        server_name domain.com www.domain.com;

        location / {

            proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
           }

}
```

This server block for the react app works as intended, however, the other app which is my API built with Laravel, MySQL, and Nginx to serve the app with docker is not working as it should.

This is the server block for the API

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name api.domain.com www.api.domain.com;
    root /var/www/public;

    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ .php$ {
    try_files $uri /index.php =404;
    fastcgi_pass 172.22.0.2:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

docker-compose file

```
version: '3'
services:

  #PHP Service
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: {docker_image:latest}
    container_name: app
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    environment:
      SERVICE_NAME: app
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
      - ./php/local.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/local.ini
    networks:
      - app-network

  #Nginx Service
  webserver:
    image: nginx:alpine
    container_name: webserver
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
      - "445:443"
    depends_on:
      - app
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
#      - ./nginx/conf.d/app.conf:/etc/nginx/sites-available/{api.domain.com}
    networks:
      - app-network

  #MySQL Service
  db:
    image: mysql:8.0
    container_name: ${APP_NAME}_db
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${DB_DATABASE}
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
      SERVICE_NAME: mysql
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./mysql/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/my.cnf
    networks:
      - app-network

#Docker Networks
networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge

#Volumes
volumes:
  dbdata:
    driver: local
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:8.0-fpm

# Copy composer.lock and composer.json
COPY composer.lock composer.json /var/www/

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /var/www

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    libpng-dev \
    libwebp-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    locales \
    zip \
    jpegoptim optipng pngquant gifsicle \
    vim \
    unzip \
    git \
    curl \
    libzip-dev

# Clear cache
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql zip exif pcntl
RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --enable-gd --with-jpeg --with-webp --with-freetype
RUN docker-php-ext-install gd

# Install composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

# Add user for laravel application
# RUN groupadd -g 1000 www
# RUN useradd -u 1000 -ms /bin/bash -g www www

# Copy existing application directory contents
COPY . /var/www

# Copy existing application directory permissions
COPY --chown=www-data:www-data . /var/www

# RUN chown -R www:www /var/www

# RUN chmod -R 755 /var/www

# Change current user to www
USER www-data

# Expose port 9000 and start php-fpm server
EXPOSE 9000
CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

Already created a symbolic link for the sites-enabled directory.

I have solved this exact problem before but I didn't document it, it has become really frustrating finding a solution this past few days.

I would really appreciate if anyone has a solution to this problem.

Comment: Check that both domain.com and api.domain.com resolve to the right IP address

Comment: @HansKilian It resolves to the right IP address, I'm using a digital ocean droplet.